# Playwright JS: Getting an error when debugging using line numbers

Tags: javascript, debugging, command-line, playwright

Playwright provides the option to use line numbers as well as the filename for debugging purpose via the command line.
As per documentation the below format needs to be used for debugging using line numbers

```bash
npx playwright test example.spec.ts:10 --debug
```

Note: I've tried the same but got an error.(Using a .js file)

**Playwright Version: 1.41.2**

**Steps to reproduce**
I've a file named `UIBasicsTest.spec.js`
And when I try to run the below command to open the debug mode, it throws an error

```bash
npx playwright test UIBasicsTest.spec.js:4 --debug
```

**Expected behavior**
I expect the debug functionality to work for specific lines as well just as mentioned in the official documentation.

**Actual behavior** 
Error:

```
Error: No tests found.
Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files.
You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments.
```

Comment: Please share all of your code and config as a [mcve]. Thanks.